# Formatting dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, date-formatting

I have a field which its format is date with time as: `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS` for example: `2000-08-12 00:00:00` I want to get just the date part and change its format to `DD/MMM/YYYY` for example the expected result of the previous example will be: `12/Aug/2000`

The field definition is: `Ddate timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()`

I read the whole page of [Date/Time Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) and other sources as well but I couldn't find any information that is helpful.

Comment: Is it stored as a `date` or as a `varchar`?

Comment: it's timestamp  see edit

Comment: Try [Data Type Formatting Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html) instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `to_char` function to format your column:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ddatte, 'dd/Mon/yyyy') FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 4):

try with:

```
to_char(your_Field, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: Yes that is what I did initially but it's not in the desired format. please note the month issue.

Comment: Minutes are called "MI" in the template patthers, not "mm" look at this site: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html